# How to use two connection strings in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I need to configure my application so that depending on a client it is connected to one database or another. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I assume that you mean dynamically when the site is running.  See [Dynamically change connection string in Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816215/dynamically-change-connection-string-in-asp-net-core) for some suggestions.

Comment: Maybe this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836102/asp-net-core-change-ef-connection-string-when-user-logs-in/40840797#40840797