# .net core web api close database connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to build a blog webapi with this web api core [demo](https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-registration-login-api) and [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc?view=aspnetcore-2.1). I use Npgsql connect to a PostgreSQL database, and add some methods, but the database return error message "too many clients connected" when I debugging.

So how to close the connections in webapi? I read some documents but can't find a way to do with it.

[my repo here](https://github.com/Rackar/aspnet-core-registration-login-api)

Comment: I got a temporary way, Add "Pooling=false;" to my ConnectionStrings, because the max of the pool is 100, just escape the pooling way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `using` block. 
This will take care of database connection closing automatically and you don't have to manually close the database connection.

eg.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   // Your database code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats a good way to do, but in my case, i copy codes ```services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(option => option.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSql")));``` like this...

Comment: You have to use dependency injection in this case. For detailed information on how to use this please refer this official documentation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Also please refer this stackoverflow link for additional knowledge - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836102/asp-net-core-change-ef-connection-string-when-user-logs-in