# EF Core with DbContext pool and multi tenancy - database per tenant

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to solve problem with multi tenancy in entity framework core. Each tenant gets own database (for historical reasons, this can not be changed).

I will use context factory as suggested on many places ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40837070/3170087), [example 2](https://medium.com/@boriszn/building-multi-tenant-web-api-using-dot-net-core-and-best-practices-8dce439bfae7), [example 3](https://medium.com/@codeprefect/multitenant-application-with-database-per-tenant-87eb33c05ac5)).

My questions are:

- can I use context pooling with this approach
- can I use `IMutableEntityType.QueryFilter` set in `OnModelCreating`

If DbContext is returned from pool, I am worrying that will link to old connection string, not new (if request was started from different tenant then where context was created).

I think I can solve migrations like this (from [second point](https://medium.com/@codeprefect/multitenant-application-with-database-per-tenant-87eb33c05ac5)):

```
foreach (var tenant in allTenants)
{
    var context = dbContextFactory.CreateDbContext(tenant, configuration);
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Besides my 2 questions. Is there anything else I should thought before start coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use query filters

No, you cannot use DbContext pooling

Comment: I added [feature request](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14625).

Comment: Now you can do it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#dbcontext-pooling