# Is there a way to change the connection string of DbContext service in Configure Method after adding it in ConfigureServices method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.2

I have 2 connection strings in my appsettings.json and I use dbContext.Database.Migrate(); in Configure method to create the database if the primary connection string that I used to create the DbContext service in ConfigureServices method was incorrect, I face Exception so I want to change the connection string of the Dbcontext service in the exception area.
How can I achieve that?

I tried to do the migration in ConfigureServices but I don't know how to create a DbContext object and how to test it.

in ConfigureServices

```
        services.AddDbContext<RedContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

in Configure

```
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RedContext>();
            var roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            // Create the Db if it doesn't exist and applies any pending migration.
            try
            {
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();// throws exception if CS is wrong
                DbSeeder.Seed(dbContext, roleManager, userManager);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {                   
                // remove old service and create new dbcontext DI service in IserviceCollection with secondary connection string
                //dbContext.Database.Migrate();
                // dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()
            }
```

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836102/asp-net-core-change-ef-connection-string-when-user-logs-in

Comment: I am using asp.net core 2.2 .

Answer (score 0):

```
YourDBContextClass dbcontext = new YourDBContextClass("alternateconnectionstringname");
```

Try this.

P.S Add a cosntructor to your DbContext to do this:

```
 public partial class YourDBContextClass
 {
    // Add a constructor to allow the connection string name to be changed
 public YourDBContextClass(string connectionStringNameInConfig)
        : base("name=" + connectionStringNameInConfig)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: The DbContext class should derive from DbContext and the Constructor doesn't accept strings, it only accepts DbContextOption object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

Create a new constructor for your Context

```
public partial class RedContext
 {
    // Add a constructor to allow the connection string name to be changed
 public RedContext(string connectionStringNameInConfig)
        : base("name=" + connectionStringNameInConfig)
    {
    }
}
```

Change Configuration:

```
 using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RedContext("alternateconnectionstringname")>();
            var roleManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var userManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            // Create the Db if it doesn't exist and applies any pending migration.
            try
            {
                dbContext.Database.Migrate();// throws exception if CS is wrong
                DbSeeder.Seed(dbContext, roleManager, userManager);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
            }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because .GetService() accepts only type of objects, not objects like RedContext("CS") .